# NSDictionary vs [String:AnyObject] in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I updated an external Swift library, and one of the methods has changed face from:

```
public convenience method(data:NSDictionary?) { ... }
```

to:

```
public convenience method(data:[String: AnyObject]?) { ... }
```

1. What does this mean?
2. Initially, with the old, `@{@"optionA":@YES}` was passed as `data`
   argument.  But now with the new I need to pass two items.  I was thinking to just write `@{@"optionA":@YES,@"optionB":@NO}`, is that correct?

Comment: You are calling the method from Obj-C?

Comment: @Sulthan Great! Yes I am calling from Obj-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It just means that the parameter is a swift dictionary now and no Objective-C NSDictionary anymore.
2. To pass data, just use square brackets instead of curly brackets and remove the "@" (in swift)

`["optionA":true, "optionB": false]`

If you are calling the method from Objective-C, the method parameter should be exposed as NSDictionary and you were right with `@{@"optionA":@YES,"optionB":@NO}` but missed a @-sign before `optionB`

Comment: Missing `@` was typo.  Thanks!